# In wicket, how can you refresh a feedbackpanel from an onSubmit of an ajax component within a panel?

Tags: java, wicket

I have a feedback panel at the top of my page.

I have a number of panels, each have sub panels with AjaxFallback links that, when clicked I want to set info() messages to be displayed in the feedback panel.

Do I *have* to pass my feedback panel down through the layers of panels in order that I can re-add it to the Ajax target when the link is clicked? Or is there another way?

Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something has to add it to the target, but there are ways of using indirection so that things don't need to be passed around as much.  See [this blog article](http://techblog.molindo.at/2008/09/wicket-loose-coupling-of-componens-for-ajax-updates.html) for one tactic.

Something similar is being added in Wicket 1.5.  See [WICKET-1312](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-1312) for bug-tracking about this addition.

Comment: Thanks for that link - gets me in the right direction. any idea when 1.5 will be stable?

Answer (score 8):

The following works in Wicket 6

```
    target.addChildren(getPage(), FeedbackPanel.class);
```